# MySQL [Warning] IP address could not be resolved

Tags: networking, mysql, domain-name-system, centos, resolv.conf

I'm running MySQL5.6.3 on a CentOS 6.1 virtual machine running on Windows XP in [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/).

The network card is configured in bridge mode, so my physical & virtual machines share the same ethernet card.

On the virtual machine, everything works fine: internet access, DNS lookups. However, connections to the MySQL daemon take a while, and the logs keep showing this warning:

> [Warning] IP address '192.168.1.201' could not be resolved: Temporary
>   failure in name resolution

`192.168.1.201` is my host machine on which I'm runnning the MySQL client.

Looks like although DNS lookups work fine, *reverse* DNS lookups end up in a timeout.

Here is the virtual machine configuration:

```
# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
DEVICE="eth0"
HWADDR="08:00:27:4B:3D:7C"
NM_CONTROLLED="yes"
ONBOOT="yes"
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
IPADDR=192.168.1.200
GATEWAY=192.168.1.1
PEERDNS=yes

# cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

Is there something wrong in my network configuration?

Comment: refer to my another answer for this question: http://serverfault.com/a/778161/96578

Answer (score 57, accepted):

IMHO This sounds like you need mysqld to stop using DNS.

Please do the following: Add this to /etc/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
skip-host-cache
skip-name-resolve
```

Them restart mysql. From then on, mysql will no longer resolve addresses via DNS.

Give it a Try !!!

CAVEAT

Please read these options in the MySQL Documentation:

- [`skip-host-cache`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_skip-host-cache)
- [`skip-name-resolve`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_skip-name-resolve)
- [`DNS Lookup Optimization and the Host Cache`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/host-cache.html)

Also, there is one restriction to using this: You cannot use DNS names in the host column of any of the grant tables.

## UPDATE 2012-12-17 08:37 EDT

I was recently asked if `skip-host-cache` and `skip-name-resolve` could be set without a mysql restart. Let's find out:

```
mysql> show variables like '%host%';
+---------------+--------------+
| Variable_name | Value        |
+---------------+--------------+
| hostname      | ************ |
| report_host   |              |
+---------------+--------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show variables like 'skip_%';
+-----------------------+-------+
| Variable_name         | Value |
+-----------------------+-------+
| skip_external_locking | ON    |
| skip_name_resolve     | OFF   |
| skip_networking       | OFF   |
| skip_show_database    | OFF   |
+-----------------------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> set global skip_name_resolve = 1;
ERROR 1238 (HY000): Variable 'skip_name_resolve' is a read only variable
mysql>
```

As shown, `skip-host-cache` is not visible in the list of global variables. As for `skip_name_resolve`, it was visible. However, it cannot changed dynamically because it is a read-only variable.

Therefore, `skip-host-cache` and `skip-name-resolve` can only be changed via a mysql restart.

Comment: Do we have any problems as effect of disabling DNS look ups ?

Comment: @Uday the only concern within mysql is this: You cannot use a DNS name effectively in the host column of `mysql.user`. If you have any, you need to replace them with the public or private (preferable) IP address instead.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA is there a way to add `skip-host-cache` and `skip-name-resolve` without restarting MySql?

Comment: @Ran Sorry, the answer is no. I updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Can there be any possible problem like connectivity from **localhost** or any other issue? I'm facing problem for ip `243.221.167.124.adsl-pool.sx.cn`

Comment: @MalayM Actually, I believe the answer for the localhost is "yes" because I had this problem. I had to update the connection to use `127.0.0.1` rather than local host. I don't remember the specifics though but I decided to leave DNS resolution enabled after have a few issues with disabling it in the environment I tried to disable it.