# MySQL Warning IP address '192.168.xx.xxx' could not be resolved: the host is not known

Tags: mysql

I have a device that is sending data to my server every minute. (No DNS is runnig). when I start my device, I am getting a warning message.

```
[Warning] IP address '192.168.xx.xxx' could not be resolved: the host is not known.
```

then every minute I am getting following warning in my mysql log file. (of course new connection number every minute. this is one sample)

```
2019-05-15 11:12:00 840 [Warning] Aborted connection 840 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'root' host: '192.168.xx.xx' (Got an error reading communication packets).
```

Eventhough there is this warning, But my device is still posting data into mysql server every minute.

I don't know why this warning says db: 'unconnected'?  Any suggestions. 
(I am using static IPs)

Comment: Seems like your client doesn't close the connection properly. For the first warning: https://serverfault.com/questions/393862/mysql-warning-ip-address-could-not-be-resolved

Comment: i noticed following warnings as well.
`[ERROR] mysqld.exe: Table '.\mysql\user' is marked as crashed and should be repaired`
`[Warning] Checking table:   '.\mysql\user'`
`[ERROR] mysql.user: 1 client is using or hasn't closed the table properly`
`[ERROR] mysqld.exe: Table '.\mysql\event' is marked as crashed and should be repaired`
`[Warning] Checking table:   '.\mysql\event'`
'[ERROR] mysql.event: 1 client is using or hasn't closed the table properly`

Comment: ...which should answer your question. You have to cleanly close the connection from your 'device'.

Comment: @sunny_old_days - A crash led to those ERRORs.  You should run `CHECK TABLE` and `REPAIR TABLE` on those tables.

Answer (score 0):

Below are reasons for such errors.

```
1. The client connected successfully but terminated improperly (and may relate to not closing the connection properly)
2. The client slept for longer than the defined wait_timeout or interactive_timeout seconds (which ends up causing the connection to sleep for wait_timeout seconds and then the connection gets forcibly closed by the MySQL server)
3. The client terminated abnormally or exceeded the max_allowed_packet for queries
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: your second point must be the reason. My device (client) is sending and receiving data from DB and to DB every minutes.

Comment: error log time is exactly same as the data received in DB.