# How to set Firewalld rules on first time and don't harm your self?

Tags: nginx, mysql, firewalld

I'm running the server on `CentOS` and `Nginx` (`nodejs` application).

I am experiencing too many connections to my `mysql` database and website goes down.

My `iotop` log shows me that `mysqld` is taking to much IO read (gigabyte/sec) when no any strange requests to app server does (confirmed by Nginx log and app log). I connected Cloudflare and the firewall logs confirms that there is no strange HTTP request activity.

The site (https://info-kurs.com) has not much visitors per day (was a lot white crawlers but I disallow them with robots.txt).

My `mysqld.log` tells me that there is a lot of error like:

```
IP address 'ХХ.ХХ.ХХ.ХХ' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
```

And then my application errored with this:

```
MySQL Error 1040: Too Many Connections
```

I read this post [MySQL warning "IP address could not be resolved"](https://serverfault.com/questions/393862/mysql-warning-ip-address-could-not-be-resolved)

It suggests me to add `skip_name_resolve` to `my.cnf` file. I added this directive. Also to setup firewall. I choose Firewalld.

**My question is** - how to set Firewalld for the first time and do not loose the ssh and http/https connection to server/site and how to prevent mysql:3306 connection from all internet except my office IP. I use workbench to have access to my DB.

For now I know:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=80/tcp
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=443/tcp
```

But how to block all connection to mysql except one IP?

Comment: Don't use `--permanent`.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Why do not use?

Comment: Because if you make a mistake and lock yourself out, you cannot recover from it.