# mysqld_multi stop doesn't seem to work

Tags: mysql

`mysqld_multi stop 1` followed by (repeatedly, a few moments later)

`mysqld_multi report 1` returns:

`Reporting MySQL servers`

`MySQL server from group: mysqld1 is running`

The instances work fine and when I reboot, I have to start the instances to get them to come back up (a separate issue I need to resolve), but the `stop` command doesn't seem to do anything.

It truly doesn't stop the instance because in the instance log file I see this:
`120619 11:12:39 mysqld_safe A mysqld process already exists` after trying to run `start` after.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Whenever this happens, I usually try to shutdown mysql using [**mysqladmin**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqladmin.html)

For example, to shutdown mysql running on port 3307

```
mysqladmin -h127.0.0.1 -P3307 -uroot -p shutdown
```

Once you ran that make sure, mysql on that port is indeed down like this:

```
mysqladmin -h127.0.0.1 -P3307 -uroot -p ping
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: `mysqld_multi report` should also shown as stopped after the shutdown command (if that's easier than running the ping)

Answer (score 2):

To stop any instance of `mysqld_multi` privileges should be granted to `multi_admin` user. Kindly check grants part also.

Comment: I had misspelled the username in my cnf file... doh.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is still present in MYSQL 5.7.7
It sounds funny but the work around is to use pass instead of password in my.cnf for [multi_admin] group user.

```
[mysqld_multi]
mysqld     = /usr/bin/mysqld_safe
mysqladmin = /usr/bin/mysqladmin
user       = multi_admin
pass       = pass123
```

Answer (score 0):

after shutting down mysql service (using `mysqladmin -h127.0.0.1 -uroot -p shutdown`) and start it again, I could not connect to that server from *external clients*

I looked up the problem and I found **[this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/341290/mysql-warning-ip-address-could-not-be-resolved)**, applied the answer, so that the problem is solved. that was because of waste DNS reverse query of mysqld.

Answer (score 0):

mysqld_multi is just a perl script. Why`mysqld_multi start 1` and `mysqld_multi report 1` working, but `mysqld_multi stop 1` not, lies in my_print_defaults.

```
my_print_defaults mysqld_multi -s

--mysqld=/usr/bin/mysqld_safe
--mysqladmin=/usr/bin/mysqladmin
--user=multi_admin
--password=yy

my_print_defaults mysqld_multi
--mysqld=/usr/bin/mysqld_safe
--mysqladmin=/usr/bin/mysqladmin
--user=multi_admin
--password=*****
```

In MySQL5.6+， password will be shown in "*" by defaults, `mysqld_multi` start, report doesn't need authorization, so password is of no use, and it workers, but when stoping, user & password is needed for authorization, and "*" breaks down `mysqld_multi stop`.

Solutions:

1. modify mysqld_multi, add `-s` option to my_print_defaults
2. mysqld_multi stop 4 --password=my_password

@RolandoMySQLDBA 's solution works, just because mysqld_multi will finally rely on mysqladmin to admin mysqld instance